# Select drop down lose $_POST value onchange form submit with IE

Tags: select, post, onchange, html-select

I have the following problem with form submit on select onchange event with IE. Mozilla is fine but on IE when I var_vump($_POST['makes']) I can se it is empty.. My form is this:

```
<form name="makes_filter" id="makes_filter" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">    
Filter by:    
<select name="makes" id="makes" style="width: 120px; text-align: left; margin-right: 5px; float: left;" onchange="document.forms.makes_filter.submit();">    
<option style="text-align: center;" value=""> -- Make -- </option>    
<option id="APPLE" value="APPLE">APPLE</option>    
<option id="HTC" value="HTC">HTC</option>    
<option id="LG" value="LG">LG</option>    
<option id="NOKIA " value="NOKIA ">NOKIA </option>    
</select>    
</form>
```

Can you please help me to find out why this form submits empty value on selected option?
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by removing another select with same name/id